# Flutter - how to connect to Facebook's SDK app event using a codeless setup

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flutter

I want to promote my apps using **Facebook ads app install** using codeless app setup :

[image]

I try and shake my phone, but I'm still not getting any response that my setup is successful (I'm using **Android** to test).

My project was built using **Flutter** (not native android) and I'm using the below Facebook SDK plugin on my `pubspec.yaml` :

```
flutter_facebook_login:
  git:
   url: https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login
   ref: e69fef3
```

Moreover, on my developer Facebook dashboard I can see events (install, launch, remove, etc). It seems the Facebook SDK has been integrated.

I also have tried to verify through [Facebook helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper) but I get no message that this app event for CPA is successful.

This message always appears when I want to setup Facebook app ads :

[image]

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: hi, nobody can help ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863180/facebook-mobile-ad-app-installs-not-showing-up-in-campaign-reports) thread?

Comment: @NarkhedeTushar yes i did, but it's native android project but mine is flutter...

Comment: @coderInrRain hi, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Cԃաԃ Hi, not yet... i'm switching to another project, so this one still abandoned. I think someone should make plugin for this

Comment: sorry to hear that... bad news for me too hehehe, have you tried this plugin ? https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events
author of the plugin says it supports codeless app events, but we have failed to make it work.

Comment: @Cԃաԃ nope...i will try... thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the native Facebook SDK. Because Facebook login doesn't send install and other analytics data. Older version of Facebook SDK have all feature but Facebook's current SDK version separated the SDK like login, core, share, place, etc. You can fix with the native solution. You can find more detail from [here](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) under STRUCTURE section

Answer (score -1):

My project was built using Flutter  and I'm using the below Facebook SDK plugin on my pubspec.yaml :

```
dependencies:
logs:
   git: https://github.com/pq/logs
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1
flutter_account_kit: 0.7.0
```